# how to write assembly language to make DMA works

Tags: assembly, io, cpu, x86-16

I know there are 3 ways to transmit the IO data:
program mode,interrupt mode and DMA mode.
And for the program mode, if I want to transmit a byte from IO to RAM, I should write like this

```
MOV PORT1,000AH        # tell io the address
IN ACC,PORT2           # read data from this address
MOV [0x5566], ACC      # mov this data to RAM
```

And if I want to transmit many bytes, I foreach this program. That's OK.
But here is my question:

**What if I want to use DMA mode,how to write my assembly language to transmit many bytes from IO to RAM?**

I know how DMA works, but I am confused about who tells them to do this?I think cpu need to tell the IO start address, the data length, the RAM address. All of this, what the assembly language should be?

I found a lot but didn't find answer. Did I miss something important that make I confused about this? I hope someone's help.Thanks

Comment: I have never programmed DMA.  But looking at SetDMAAddress [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/dma-controller-programming-in-c/184402798), it seems you are right.  There are several `out` instructions to set up addresses for page ports and address ports as well as addition `out`s to enable, and set the mode.  As well as a bunch of other stuff that frankly I don't understand.  Hopefully those pages help though.

Comment: Thanks for answer, how to write this asm? just transmit many bytes from IO to RAM. For example transmit from IO(0000h~00FFh) to RAM(0000h~00FFh), just this

Comment: [This article](https://wiki.osdev.org/ISA_DMA) might be helpful.

Comment: It's hard to answer since the tags say "x86" but the code is not x86 assembly. Without knowing the architecture we can't answer but conceptually.

Comment: The whole point of DMA is that the CPU is not involved; a peripheral temporarily takes control of the bus and uses it to directly access memory. The peripheral _may_ be triggered by the CPU to do so, but if and how that is the case, entirely depends on the architecture of the subsystem. "To transmit the IO data" is too generic; your question can only be answered for a specific peripheral device.

Comment: Depends entirely on the CPU and the machine running it. Every computer is going to have a different procedure for it. Your typical Windows/Mac/Linux PC might do it differently from an embedded device.

Comment: I should clarify, even two different platforms that both use the same CPU can have different DMA procedures. It all depends on the external hardware.

Answer (score 1):

There is a book with the very long title:

**"THE INTEL MICROPROCESSORS
8086/8088, 80186/80188, 80286, 80386,
80486, Pentium, Pentium Pro Processor,
Pentium II, Pentium III, Pentium 4, and Core2
with 64-Bit Extensions
Architecture, Programming, and Interfacing
Eighth Edition
BARRY B. BREY"**

the example from the book:

```
;A procedure that transfers a block of data using the 8237A
;DMA controller in Figure 13–12. This is a memory-to-memory
;transfer.
;Calling parameters:
; SI = source address
; DI = destination address
; CX = count
; ES = segment of source and destination
LATCHB EQU 10H
CLEARF EQU 7CH
CHOA EQU 70H
CH1A EQU 72H
CH1C EQU 73H
MODE EQU 7BH
CMMD EQU 78H
MASKS EQU 7FH
REQ EQU 79H
STATUS EQU 78H
TRANS PROC NEAR USES AX
MOV AX,ES                ;program latch B
MOV AL,AH
SHR AL,4
OUT LATCHB,AL
OUT CLEARF,AL             ;clear F/L
MOV AX,ES                 ;program source address
SHL AX,4
ADD AX,SI
OUT CH0A,AL
MOV AL,AH
OUT CH0A
MOV AX,ES                 ;program destination address
SHL AX,4
ADD AX,DI
OUT CH1A,AL
MOV AL,AH
OUT CH1A,AL
MOV AX,CX                   ;program count
DEC AX
OUT CH1C,AL
MOV AL,AH
OUT CH1C,AL
MOV AL,88H              ;program mode
OUT MODE,AL
MOV AL,85H
OUT MODE,AL
MOV AL,1            ;enable block transfer
OUT CMMD,AL
MOV AL,0EH             ;unmask channel 0
OUT MASKS,AL
MOV AL,4                 ;start DMA
OUT REQ,AL
.REPEAT               ;wait for completion
IN AL,STATUS
.UNTIL AL & 1
RET
TRANS ENDP
```

Also, exactly the same piece of code can be found [here](http://www.unife.it/ing/lm.infoauto/sistemi-elaborazione/dispense/csf04_12.pdf)